# How to add a separator between English and Arabic Text in a cell

Tags: excel, vba, insert

I'm working on a workbook where I insert manually mixed English and Arabic text in the same cell "D" this text contain the section code and unit number in English in addition to some description in Arabic like this for example (NH7B-AV-06A-23 تم الانتهاء من العمل خلال 48 ساعه) in this text (NH7B) is the section code and (AV-06A-23) is the unit number... then in column "C" I have a formula to extract the "section code" (=LEFT(E7,SEARCH("-",E7)-1) and this is ok no problem at all... and in column "E" i have another formula to extract the "unit number (=MID(E70,SEARCH("-",E7)+1,FIND("@",E7)-SEARCH("-",E7)-1) ....by this way and in order to make the formula in "E" run, I have to add @ symbol to my text in column "D" manually and now i need it to be added automatically

One of my friends created a code for me to run it with a button after inserting text to D but it has one problem: it removes the formula in column "E" and extract all the english text from "D" to "E" not only the unit number....

I need your help please to fix this issue in the code or if you have any new suggestions will be appreciated

```
Sub englishATarabic()
    Dim txt As String, L, r, count As Long
    For r = 1 To ActiveSheet.Cells(ActiveSheet.Rows.count, "E").End(xlUp).Row
        If IsNumeric(ActiveSheet.Range("B" & r).Value) And ActiveSheet.Range("B" & r).Value <> "" And ActiveSheet.Range("E" & r).Value <> "" Then
            If InStr(ActiveSheet.Range("E" & r).Text, "@") < 1 Then
                count = 0
                For L = 1 To Len(ActiveSheet.Range("E" & r).Text)
                    Debug.Print L, AscW(Mid(ActiveSheet.Range("E" & r).Text, L, 1))
                    If AscW(Mid(ActiveSheet.Range("E" & r).Text, L, 1)) < 1000 Then count = count + 1 Else Exit For
                Next
                txt = Trim(Left(ActiveSheet.Range("E" & r).Text, count))
                If InStrRev(txt, "-") = Len(txt) Then ActiveSheet.Range("D" & r).Value = Trim(Left(txt, Len(txt) - 1)) Else ActiveSheet.Range("D" & r).Value = txt
            End If
        End If
    Next
End Sub
```

Comment: Why do you need to insert a character at all? The Arabic script starts with the first `space`, so couldn't you use `=MID(D7, FIND("-",D7)+1,FIND(" ",D7)-FIND("-",D7)-1)`?

Comment: @Ron Rosenfeld thanks- I want to add the character in order to let the formula in "E" run because it depends on it and this is the formula that I know so far . I dont mind of course to use a formula instead without adding anything - I have tested your good formula but unfortunately not working with all my texts because sometimes I receive the text with one or two space in the middle of english text and the space between Arabic and English is not a default but sometimes without space for example like this (NH01- 27 NEW 67-تم تحديث العقد مع العميل) if you can you fix that it would be perfect

Comment: this formula is working perfectly whatever spaces in the middle of text (=MID(E729,SEARCH("-",E729)+1,FIND("@",E729)-SEARCH("-",E729)-1) but my only problem is to add @ synmbol manually in column "D" at the end of English text

Comment: Are the right-most English characters always "-" and zero or more digits or English letters? ... If so, this becomes a regular expression problem that can be solved by editing your vba script.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your method (of determining the position of the first Arabic character) can be used without VBA in various ways.
However, please note that your method will leave a trailing hyphen for the `Unit` in your second example mentioned in your comment.

To replicate your method, using formulas, assuming you have `365`, you could use this function. Note that I had to add a specific step to remove that trailing hyphen (`tUnit`)

*(Note that in both the formula and the Power Query methods, we test for an Arabic character by looking for a character code greater than 255. In a more complex scenario, we could test specifically for the arabic character set, but, at present, this comprises `1519` characters in `11` separate groupings, so would add considerable complexity to the formula. However, if applicable to your dataset, you could just test for the range `0600-06FF`. You'd need to investigate whether that is sufficient.)*

```
B2: =LET(
    firstHyphen, FIND("-", A2),
    firstArabic, XMATCH(TRUE, UNICODE(MID(A2, SEQUENCE(LEN(A2)), 1)) > 255),
    section, LEFT(A2, firstHyphen - 1),
    unit, TRIM(MID(A2, firstHyphen + 1, firstArabic - firstHyphen - 1)),
    tUnit, IF(RIGHT(unit) = "-", LEFT(unit, LEN(unit) - 1), unit),
    arb, MID(A2, firstArabic, 255),
    HSTACK(section, tUnit, arb)
)
```

and fill down. The results `SPILL` into the adjacent columns

[image]

This can also be accomplished using Power Query, available in Windows Excel 2010+ and Excel 365 (Windows or Mac)

To use Power Query

- Select some cell in your Data Table
- `Data => Get&Transform => from Table/Range` or `from within sheet`
- When the PQ Editor opens: `Home => Advanced Editor`
- Make note of the Table **Name** in Line 2
- Paste the M Code below in place of what you see
- Change the Table name in line 2 back to what was generated originally.
- Read the comments and explore the `Applied Steps` to understand the algorithm

Note that it is easier to trim that trailing hyphen.

```
let
    Source = Excel.CurrentWorkbook(){[Name="Table30"]}[Content],
    #"Changed Type" = Table.TransformColumnTypes(Source,{{"Column1", type text}}),
    
//determine positions on which to split the string
    #"Split Positions" = Table.AddColumn(#"Changed Type","Splits", (c)=>
        let 
            firstHyphen = Text.PositionOf(c[Column1],"-"),

        //1st Arabic character assumed to be first character with a character code > 255
            firstArabic = 
                List.PositionOf(
                    List.Transform(
                        Text.ToList(c[Column1]), 
                    each Character.ToNumber(_)>255),true,Occurrence.First),

        //"0" is first position in PQ
            splits={0,firstHyphen,firstArabic},
            texts = Splitter.SplitTextByPositions(splits)(c[Column1]),

        //Trim any leading/trailing spaces or hyphens. Other characters can be added to this list to trim
            trims = List.Transform(texts, each Text.Trim(_,{" ","-"}))
        in 
            Record.FromList(trims,{"Section","Unit","Description"}), type record),
    
    #"Expanded Splits" = Table.ExpandRecordColumn(#"Split Positions", "Splits", {"Section", "Unit", "Description"})
in
    #"Expanded Splits"
```

[image]

*`Column1` can be deleted from the final table in PQ if that is preferable*

If, for some reason, you prefer to use VBA, you can write a UDF that will do the entire splitting task, and then use that function on your worksheet. eg:

```
Option Explicit
Function splitWithArabic(s As String)
    Dim RE As Object, MC As Object
    Dim I As Long
    Dim vParts(0 To 2)
    
'Initialize regular expression object
Set RE = CreateObject("vbscript.regexp")
With RE
    .Pattern = "^([^-\s]*)[-\s]+([^\u0600-\u06FF]+)[-\s]+(.*)"
    .MultiLine = True
    If .test(s) = True Then
        Set MC = .Execute(s)
        For I = 0 To 2
            vParts(I) = MC(0).submatches(I)
        Next I
    End If
End With
splitWithArabic = vParts
        
End Function
```

*The function will return a three element array. Depending on your version of Excel, it may either `SPILL` to the three columns, or you may need to array-enter it across the three columns, or use the INDEX function to return each element of the array*

### ***Explanation of the Regex used***
^([^-\s]*)[-\s]+([^\u0600-\u06FF]+)[-\s]+(.*)

```
^([^-\s]*)[-\s]+([^\u0600-\u06FF]+)[-\s]+(.*)
```

Options: Case insensitive; ^$ match at line breaks

- [Assert position at the beginning of a line](https://www.regular-expressions.info/anchors.html) `^`
- [Match the regex below and capture its match into backreference number 1](https://www.regular-expressions.info/modifiers.html) `([^-\s]*)`

  - [Match any single character NOT present in the list below](https://www.regular-expressions.info/charclass.html) `[^-\s]*`

    - [Between zero and unlimited times, as many times as possible, giving back as needed (greedy)](https://www.regular-expressions.info/repeat.html) `*`
    - [The literal character “-”](https://www.regular-expressions.info/characters.html) `-`
    - [A “whitespace character”](https://www.regular-expressions.info/shorthand.html) `\s`
- [Match a single character present in the list below](https://www.regular-expressions.info/charclass.html) `[-\s]+`

  - [Between one and unlimited times, as many times as possible, giving back as needed (greedy)](https://www.regular-expressions.info/repeat.html) `+`
  - [The literal character “-”](https://www.regular-expressions.info/characters.html) `-`
  - [A “whitespace character”](https://www.regular-expressions.info/shorthand.html) `\s`
- [Match the regex below and capture its match into backreference number 2](https://www.regular-expressions.info/modifiers.html) `([^\u0600-\u06FF]+)`

  - [Match any single character NOT in the range between these two characters](https://www.regular-expressions.info/charclass.html) `[^\u0600-\u06FF]+`

    - [Between one and unlimited times, as many times as possible, giving back as needed (greedy)](https://www.regular-expressions.info/repeat.html) `+`
    - [The Unicode character with code point U+0600](https://www.regular-expressions.info/unicode.html#codepoint) `\u0600`
    - [The character “ۿ” which occupies Unicode code point U+06FF](https://www.regular-expressions.info/unicode.html#codepoint) `\u06FF`
- [Match a single character present in the list below](https://www.regular-expressions.info/charclass.html) `[-\s]+`

  - [Between one and unlimited times, as many times as possible, giving back as needed (greedy)](https://www.regular-expressions.info/repeat.html) `+`
  - [The literal character “-”](https://www.regular-expressions.info/characters.html) `-`
  - [A “whitespace character”](https://www.regular-expressions.info/shorthand.html) `\s`
- [Match the regex below and capture its match into backreference number 3](https://www.regular-expressions.info/modifiers.html) `(.*)`

  - [Match any single character that is NOT a line break character](https://www.regular-expressions.info/dot.html) `.*`

    - [Between zero and unlimited times, as many times as possible, giving back as needed (greedy)](https://www.regular-expressions.info/repeat.html) `*`

Created with [RegexBuddy](https://www.regexbuddy.com/)